# How to ask to change location of interview?

Tags: interviewing, travel, location, malaysia

I got an invitation for an interview in Kuala Lumpur, but I am in Sabah which is about 1600km away across the sea. How do I reply the interviewer email asking to change the interview to my local office instead?

Comment: Just be honest and ask him. Write him an email kindly explaining your request and your reasons why. If you communicated with the interviewer via phone, then a quick call could be better option.

Comment: Where will you work if you are offered the job?

Comment: I second @MaskedMan. If you will be working in Kuala Lumpur, then it is likely that the hiring manager and team are there as well. It makes more sense to have you travel than to have you interview with someone else. Also, keep in mind that often the company will pay for any travel expenses for interviews.

Comment: You may also find this question useful: [Is it fine to ask employer to interview me via Skype when it is an out-of-state job interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22490/is-it-fine-to-ask-employer-to-interview-me-via-skype-when-it-is-an-out-of-state)

Comment: Reply with a **short** sentence: "I'm in Sabah, could the initial interview be in Sabah or by Skype?"

Answer (score 10):

> How to reply the interviewer email to possibly change the venue to
>   GSC office at sabah instead?

Just be honest and ask.  Most reasonable people will be able to accommodate the first interview.  The real question you need to address is *where will the actual job be based out of?*

Again, be honest regarding the hardship the distance introduces for the initial interview, and meeting at the local office or Skype as a viable option.

You could send an email along the lines of:

*Hello HR Person.*

*I reside in Sabah, which is 1600 km away from you. Could the initial interview be held at the local office or via Skype?*

*Or as an alternative, would the company be willing to cover travel expenses for an on-site interview?*